# each loop only showing first value

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, append

i am trying to create a dynamic nav bar. But at the moment its only listing the first li even tho i inputted more than 1

```
    var liCount = $('.navLiName').length;
    var liName = $('.navLiName').val();

    for($i = 0; $i < liCount; $i++){
        var lis = '<li class="pi-nav-li">'+liName+'</li>';
    }

    $('.preview').append('<nav class="pi-nav">'+lis+'</nav>');
```

And this is the html

```
<input type="text" class="navLiName" /> 
<input type="text" class="navLiName" />
<input type="text" class="navLiName" />
```

So when i put i put in the above textfields: 'About', 'Service' and 'Contact' it will output it like so

```
<nav>
<li>About</li>
</nav>
```

but it should be. What have i done wrong

```
<nav>
<li>About</li>
<li>Service</li> 
<li>Contact</li>
</nav>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SJG8W/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting $lis each time the loop runs, instead of appending.
And $liName is only holding the result of the first list name, it never gets the others.

Comment: Look at the example at the very bottom of this [link](http://api.jquery.com/val/), as it's relevant to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var liCount = $('.navLiName').length;
for( var i = 0; i < liCount; i++){
    var loopLi= $('.navLiName')[i];
    alert ($(loopLi).val());
}
```